# Using genetic algorithm to tune learning machines

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, genetic-algorithms

I'm playing with tuning learning machines (specifically a random forest and a support vector machine) using genetic algorithms in R.

The only real complication that I've encountered is developing a good evaluation function.  Specifically, I realized I wanted a function which would optimize the tuning parameters by reducing both bias and variance.  Reducing bias was simple enough, but reducing variance proved a bit more tricky.  In the end, I opted for the following evaluation function:

[image]

This yields the following 3D surface:

[image]

This is almost what I want.  It maximizes when both errors are small (minimizes bias) and provides a continuous local maximum where both errors are equal (minimizes variance).

I'm not real experienced in inventing error surfaces, so I thought I'd post my initial efforts here to see if someone has some guidance or, perhaps, a better idea than me of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: your error surface aside : ooc: in what sense is this a genetic algorithm?

Comment: I'm addressing the evaluation function only, here.  The genetic algorithm package I'm using is the GA library available on CRAN.  I'm really only concerned with whether or not I can encourage the GA's ability to find an optimal solution more easily by engineering where local extrema occur in the error surface that the evaluation function provides.

Comment: OK - I re-read your OP and it is relatively clear on that. Interesting question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to experiment with meta-heuristics for hyperparameter optimization, I strongly suggest having a look at Optunity ([documentation](http://docs.optunity.net) and [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.1114.pdf)), which is an open source library that does exactly that. The default optimizer is particle swarm optimization, which we have found to perform very well on a large variety of problems, but we also offer the covariance matrix adaptation evolutionary strategy.

In terms of objective function: training performance is usually entirely irrelevant. Most objective functions work based on a cross-validation estimate of some performance metric (e.g. MSE, $R^2$, AUROC, ...). Optunity's cross-validation features allow you to compute every statistic you might want based on cross-validation, so you could incorporate variance if you'd like.